# cpp - std average

Tags: c++, average

Is there the better way to calculate the average of two doubles? How could I improve / correct my code below?

```
double original_one, original_two; // can be any double >= 0 
double used_one = original_one;
double used_two = original_two;
if ( original_one == 0 ) used_one = 1;
if ( original_two == 0 ) used_two = 1;
double average = used_one * used_two / 2;    // average!
```

Comment: Why do you need a special case for 0?

Comment: That is not how you calculate an average. Average = Sum / Count

Comment: @Fanael maybe does not need. I use it because `0 * any_number = 0`

Comment: Wait..yeah this isn't even remotely close to an average...

Comment: @abrahab : But what makes you think you need `*` at all?

Comment: @ildjarn ymmm... maybe my mistake :(

Comment: What definition of "average" are you using?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: That's how you do an arithmetic mean. It's also possible to do (for example) a geometric mean, which would be `sqrt(a*b)`. There's also harmonic mean, etc. But you're generally right, that absent an indication to the contrary, "average" means "arithmetic mean".

Comment: It is definitely possible to make it shorter, but it will not be more readable.
BTW. usually average is `(a+b)/2`. I'm curious where from you took this definition of "average"

Comment: I need count average at cpp. its seems my logical mistake with `*`. I will use this average to make the clean rating. Its the relative values.

Comment: Why must the doubles be `>= 0`? The "arithmetic mean" of -5 and 5 is 0...

Comment: @Drise this comment is about my application values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arithmetic mean of two numbers is computed by adding them, and dividing by two...

```
double average = (original_one + original_two) / 2;
```

This is one way to compute the average, there are several more but this is the most common.

Comment: That is the arithmetic mean. Average can be mean many different things (although I haven't come across anything looking like OP's average)

Comment: @juanchopanza Average is a measure of central tendency, so yes you are right there are many different methods for finding the average. However the OP's is NOT a measure of central tendency. His will always result in a value that is outside the range of values (nothing central about it). I will edit to reflect the particular method chosen however. Thanks.

Comment: I need any `relative` value of two doubles to create rating. the simple average with `+` seems is ok to show the weight of two and compere it with others